# Multiple db context in a ASP.NET 7.0 razor pages web application

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages

I would like to make an ASP.NET 7.0 razor pages web application can access different databases depending on the user used after it has passed the authentication phase.

In practice, user "U1" can access the database "DBU1", user "U2" to "DBU2" and user "U*n*" to "DBU*n*" according to a user/connString mapping present in a json file or table of a specific database.

There may be a case that a user can access multiple databases in which case the user will have to choose the database via a combobox.

Different database types could also be used (for example: mssql, postgre, oracle).

Is there anyone who can kindly give me some suggestions?

Thank you.

sf

Comment: Hi @steve fax, you could create tables with User and Connection string many-to-many relationship. Then according to the relationship to list the combobox.